# How to replace special Character with a String replacer

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have the following Code:

```
@Test
public void testReplace(){

    int asciiVal = 233;
    String str = new Character((char) asciiVal).toString();
    String oldName = "Fr" + str + "d" + str + "ric";
    System.out.println(oldName);

    String newName = oldName.replace("é", "_");
    System.out.println(newName);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(oldName, newName); // Its still equal. Howto Replace with a String

    String notTheWayILike = oldName.replace((char) 233 + "", "_"); // I don't want to do this.
    Assert.assertNotEquals(oldName, notTheWayILike);
}
```

How can I replace the character with a String ? 
I need this, because they should be userfriendly defined as Strings or chars.

Comment: `I don't want to do this` -> why?

Comment: Your test passes. My guess is that your file is encoded using an encoding, but your compiler uses another one.

Comment: It worked for me. maybe try `String newName = oldName.replace(str, "_");` and see if it works

Comment: @JB Nizet. Ok, that sounds interresting. My first Assert fails and yours is green ? Where can I check encoding for compiler. I couldn't find it in settings.

Comment: Thanks for helping to all. You brought my on the right way. I checked out my project on a new computer/IntelliJ.  My file was already encoded in UTF-8. I had to convert it to ISO and back to UTF-8. Then it worked. This is unreliable after a fresh checkout. I wondering, howto handle this correctly with GIT.